# FOR XML path open/close

Tags: sql, xml, path, sql-server-2014

I have a issue on a FOR XML PATH clause i am currently using. what i want it to look like i following:

```
<forecastImport>
<ctForecast>
<ctID>2</ctID>
<forecastData>
<date><day>24</day><month>12</month><year>2014</year></date>
<periodData>
<time>00:00</time>
<contactsReceived>0</contactsReceived>
</periodData>
<periodData>
<time>00:15</time>
<contactsReceived>0</contactsReceived>
</periodData>
<periodData>
<time>00:30</time>
<contactsReceived>0</contactsReceived>
</periodData>
<periodData>
<time>00:45</time>
<contactsReceived>0</contactsReceived>
</periodData>
<periodData>
<time>01:00</time>
<contactsReceived>0</contactsReceived>
</periodData>
......
<periodData>
<time>23:15</time>
<contactsReceived>0</contactsReceived>
</periodData>
<periodData>
<time>23:30</time>
<contactsReceived>0</contactsReceived>
</periodData>
<periodData>
<time>23:45</time>
<contactsReceived>0</contactsReceived>
</periodData>
</forecastData>
</ctForecast>
```

This is how it should be, but no matter what i do i get this result:

```
<forecastImport>
  <ctForecast>
    <CTID>2</CTID>
    <forecastData>
      <date>
        <day>13</day>
        <month>10</month>
        <year>2015</year>
      </date>
      <periodData>
        <Time>08:00:00</Time>
      </periodData>
      <contacsReceived>
        <periodData>5.05004</periodData>
      </contacsReceived>
    </forecastData>
  </ctForecast>
  <ctForecast>
    <CTID>2</CTID>
    <forecastData>
      <date>
        <day>13</day>
        <month>10</month>
        <year>2015</year>
      </date>
      <periodData>
        <Time>08:15:00</Time>
      </periodData>
      <contacsReceived>
        <periodData>5.24004</periodData>
      </contacsReceived>
    </forecastData>
  </ctForecast>
  <ctForecast>
```

the forecastData should close after an entire day, not each time interval. i am using following query:

```
SELECT
      --[ID]
       [CTID]
      ,[forecastData/date/day] = Day(dDate) 
      ,[forecastData/date/month] = month(dDate)
      ,[forecastData/date/year] = year(dDate)
      ,[dtmInterval] AS [forecastData/periodData/Time]
      ,[CO_Forecast] AS [forecastData/contacsReceived/periodData]
      --,[AHT_Forecast]          
  FROM [ProductionForecast].[dbo].[Forecast]

  FOR XML PATH ('ctForecast'), ROOT ('forecastImport')
```

i really dont know what to do, i have just learned the for XML clause and is only familiar with PATH and AUTO at the moment. I am using Microsoft SQL 2014.

This is the table structure:

```
CTID    forecastData/date/day   forecastData/date/month forecastData/date/year  periodData/Time contacsReceived/periodData
2   13  10  2015    08:00:00    5.05004
2   13  10  2015    08:15:00    5.24004
2   13  10  2015    08:30:00    4.49004
2   13  10  2015    08:45:00    4.50004
2   13  10  2015    09:00:00    5.65004
2   13  10  2015    09:15:00    7.00006
2   13  10  2015    09:30:00    7.12006
2   13  10  2015    09:45:00    7.39006
2   13  10  2015    10:00:00    8.51007
2   13  10  2015    10:15:00    7.86006
```

thank you.
kind regards.

Comment: It is not really obvious, how your "I want" and your "I have" section fit together. Please state your tables structure with some sample data. Especially your ContactsRecieved seem to be a counter in the "I want" and seem to be kind of ID in your "I have" section. Be aware, that you want to create nested hierarchies...

Comment: Hi. thank you for your answer.
What i want is the first XML structure, but what i have is the second, i dont know how to rewrite the SQL query to get the second XML structure.

Comment: Yes, this was clear, but please read my comment once again and answer the questions, thx

Comment: im sorry, but then i dont know what your question is?

Comment: In your first section there are "ContactsRecieved" nodes with zeros. In you r second section there are sub-nodes "periodData" with kind of code...

Comment: Please poste your table's structure with some lines of sample data.

Comment: I have updated the original question with the table structure, i hope it will suffice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try it like this:

Just paste the whole code in an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(CTID INT,day INT,month INT,year INT,Time TIME,periodData VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (2,13,10,2015,{t'08:00:00'},'5.05004')
,(2,13,10,2015,{t'08:15:00'},'5.24004')
,(2,13,10,2015,{t'08:30:00'},'4.49004')
,(2,13,10,2015,{t'08:45:00'},'4.50004')
,(2,13,10,2015,{t'09:00:00'},'5.65004')
,(2,13,10,2015,{t'09:15:00'},'7.00006')
,(2,13,10,2015,{t'09:30:00'},'7.12006')
,(2,13,10,2015,{t'09:45:00'},'7.39006')
,(2,13,10,2015,{t'10:00:00'},'8.51007')
,(2,13,10,2015,{t'10:15:00'},'7.86006');

WITH DistinctIDs AS --assuming that in your original data there are more IDs
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CTID 
    FROM @tbl
)
,DistinctDates AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CTID
                   ,day
                   ,month
                   ,year 
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT DistinctIDs.CTID 
      ,DistinctDates.*
FROM DistinctIDs
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  dd.day   AS [date/day]
           ,dd.month AS [date/month]
           ,dd.year  AS [date/year]
           ,PeriodData.periodData AS [node()]
    FROM DistinctDates AS dd
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT pd.Time AS [time]
              ,0 AS [contactsRecieved] --Don't know the meaning of this "0"... All example lines are the same...              
        FROM @tbl AS pd
        WHERE pd.CTID=DistinctIDs.CTID
          AND pd.day = dd.day
          AND pd.month = dd.month
          AND pd.year = dd.year
        FOR XML PATH('periodData'),TYPE
    ) AS PeriodData(periodData) 
    WHERE dd.CTID=DistinctIDs.CTID
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
) AS DistinctDates(forecastData)
FOR XML PATH('ctForecast'), ROOT('forecastImport')
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to help me, it means alot to me. I am currently running your query, although it has been changed a bit, but since it is going through roughly 600.000 rows, it will probably take a while :) but it looks like it will work. It had the right XML layout with the @tbl you made, so im sure it will work on the full size table. 

Besides, the '0' was the amount of calls on the different CTID (CTID = ID of application), so thats why it was 0, the department with CTID wasnt/isnt open on that specific date :)